# Automatic tools for processing C header files in Rust?

Tags: rust, header-files, ffi

I have a C header file with various enums and typedefs and structs defined.

Are there any awesome tools out there for turning that into a Rust file?

Comment: Not into a Rust file, but check https://github.com/mystor/rust-cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never tried it, but there is [rust-bindgen](https://github.com/crabtw/rust-bindgen)...